# Как правильно использовать интерфейс метода в React class-based component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Допустим, у меня есть какой-то метод с кучей аргументов:

```
method(foo: { bar: string | number; baz: Array<string> }, bar: number, baz: 'foo' | 'boo') {
    // do smth
}
```

Я решил написать интерфейс, который можно было бы использовать как при декларировании этого метода, так и при его вызове в дочерних компонентах:

```
interface MyMethodFunc {
    (foo: { bar: string | number; baz: Array<string> }, bar: number, baz: 'foo' | 'boo'): void
}

// child component

interface MyChildComponentProps {
    onChange: MyMethodFunc
}
```

Но в таком случае я могу использовать этот интерфейс только так:

```
method: MyMethodFunc = function(foo, bar, baz) {
    // do smth
}
```

Это ломает логику и `this` класса становится недоступен

> An outer value of 'this' is shadowed by this container.

Это можно исправить сделав функцию стрелочной, но тогда это уже не устраивает меня, поскольку я предпочитаю использовать `bind` заместо объявление стрелочных функций.

Перечитал документацию TypeScript по объявлению функций, но не нашёл решение своей проблемы. Можно ли вообще как-то скастовать интерфейс на метод не изменяя алгоритм?

Comment: `class Foo implements IFoo`, тогда в классе интерфейс функции уже будет

Answer (score 0):

[http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=24&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAJAZgewQHgCoD4oF4oApgAWAlgM4BcUqANFAHT0CGATgOblQMB2IA2gLoBKbJi4gAUGIDGCTiWBRECAMwV4SZAEVMOOAFdOk4ERl4hAbyiFStAI42oAXzFFOwCEzgNJ0DVDNioQKgAIwYALwp8YnYNGnpaZjYKUX4hLBFuMSdJABsGEhIoX38gqDsKOSYXFmwoAHI6iVLFAEZVRWQrEm1TYT9LaNt7J2akACZ29S6evQMjE1xzAes7RwCgxSVazaag0KYKDVoYfe39Q2NOXosuobWnTgYAWwgSMC8fP3XAiAAPMAQTHkoEgsFOOCipEOcUYrHYKUEfVEWQk0lk8nsOE4EAA7kUxDZaKEwmc5pdrt9liQhiigA)

```
type $foo<T> = (this: T, ...args: any[]) => any

const foo3: $foo<Q> = function () { this.qq }
interface Q {
    baz: (this: Q, ...args: any[]) => any
}
class Q {
    qq: string = ''

    foo1: $foo<this> = () => { this.qq }
    foo2: $foo<this> = function () { this.qq }
    foo3 = foo3

    bar: Q.$bar = function () { this.qq }

    constructor() {
        this.baz = function () {
            this.qq
        }

    }
}
namespace Q {
    export type $bar = (this: Q, ...args: any[]) => any
}
```

- http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#basic-concepts

Comment: почему это выглядит так страшно?

Comment: Если вы про форматирование - с телефона